# Console.log button function for each React component

Tags: reactjs

How can I console.log some text when a button is pressed? The buttons are showing up with each component but I don't understand why I cannot get an event to occur when they are pressed.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import airbnbs from './airbnbs.json';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

var Card = props => (
<div>
<div>
  <img src={props.image} height="164px" width="246px" alt=""></img>
  </div>
  <button onClick={this.addRental}>Add Rental</button>
      </div>
)

Card.propTypes={
image: PropTypes.string,
}


class Airbnblocation extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        locations: airbnbs
    };
    this.addRental = this.addRental.bind(this);
}

addRental = () => {
    console.log("hi");
}
render() {
    let locations = this.state.locations.map((locations, idx) => {
        return(
          <Card key={idx}
          image={locations.image}
          />
        )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      {locations} 
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default Airbnblocation;
```

Comment: ... `addRental` is defined in `Airbnblocation`, not `Card`.

Comment: Unrelated, but IMO it should be called `<AirBnbLocation >` so it's not just a wall of text.

Comment: Also you don’t have to bind the addRental method in constructor because you are using fat arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addRental function needs to be accessed from props

```
var Card = props => (
<div>
    <div>
  <img src={props.image} height="164px" width="246px" alt=""></img>
  </div>
  <button onClick={props.addRental}>Add Rental</button>
      </div>
)
```

and before that you would need to pass that on to the Card component like

```
render() {
    let locations = this.state.locations.map((locations, idx) => {
        return(
          <Card key={idx}
          image={locations.image} 
          addRental={this.addRental}
          />
        )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      {locations} 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: And include the corresponding `prop` when you render `<Card />`. If, in fact, the action is supposed to be handled by `<Airbnblocation />`, which is somewhat unclear.